# comma separated list of string convert into date in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I have 1 query as given below where a parameter with name "ListOfDate" which is coming by front end in form of string..i have "ENCOUNTERDATE" in mysql with datetime datatype..

```
SELECT d.encounterdate, 
       d.hospitalid, 
       amiop1, 
       amiop2, 
       amiop3, 
       amiop4, 
       amiop5, 
       amiop16 
FROM   factopami f, 
       dimpatientencounter d 
WHERE  d.hospitalid = 987654 
       AND d.measurecategory = 'AMI' 
       AND ( encounterdate IN ( ** listofdate ** ) 
              OR encounterdate IS NULL ) 
       AND d.patientid = f.patientid 
       AND d.id = f.patientencounterid 
ORDER  BY encounterdate;
```

after it i tried to convert ListOfDate into date:

```
 SELECT   d.encounterdate, d.hospitalid, amiop1, amiop2, amiop3, amiop4,
         amiop5, amiop16
    FROM factopami f, dimpatientencounter d
   WHERE d.hospitalid = 987654
     AND d.measurecategory = 'AMI'
     AND (   encounterdate IN (str_to_date ('01-10-2012' '%m-%d-%Y'))
          OR encounterdate IS NULL
         )
     AND d.patientid = f.patientid
     AND d.ID = f.patientencounterid
ORDER BY encounterdate;
```

which is working for single string ...but i got list of string which is giving me error..

```
SELECT d.encounterdate, 
       d.hospitalid, 
       amiop1, 
       amiop2, 
       amiop3, 
       amiop4, 
       amiop5, 
       amiop16 
FROM   factopami f, 
       dimpatientencounter d 
WHERE  d.hospitalid = 987654 
       AND d.measurecategory = 'AMI' 
       AND ( encounterdate IN ( Str_to_date('01-10-2012', '01-10-2012', 
                                '%m-%d-%Y') ) 
              OR encounterdate IS NULL ) 
       AND d.patientid = f.patientid 
       AND d.id = f.patientencounterid 
ORDER  BY encounterdate;
```

LIMIT 0, 1000  Error Code: 1582. Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'STR_TO_DATE'    0.000 sec

so how can i convert it to on mysql level

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In short** - at the moment you're converting the list to:

```
(encounterdate IN ( STR_TO_DATE('01-10-2012','01-10-2012', '%m-%d-%Y'))
```

Instead, you need to convert it to:

```
( encounterdate IN ( STR_TO_DATE('01-10-2012', '%m-%d-%Y')
                   , STR_TO_DATE('01-10-2012', '%m-%d-%Y') )
```

**As more of an explanation**, the IN operator is expecting a list of things:

```
encounterdate IN ( thing1, thing2, thing3 )
```

The thing you are passing is a date, meaning you're doing this:

```
encounterdate IN ( date1, date2, date3 )
```

Alas, you have strings instead of dates, and so you need to convert each of those strings into dates.  Thus you need to some conversions.

```
date1 needs to be STR_TO_DATE( string1, '%m-%d-%y )
date2 needs to be STR_TO_DATE( string2, '%m-%d-%y )
date3 needs to be STR_TO_DATE( string3, '%m-%d-%y )
```

Putting that all together, you need to generate:

```
encounterdate IN ( STR_TO_DATE('01-10-2012', '%m-%d-%Y')
                 , STR_TO_DATE('01-10-2012', '%m-%d-%Y')
                 , STR_TO_DATE('01-10-2012', '%m-%d-%Y')
```

**As an alternative**, if you feel it's not possible to produce this, you could flip the conversion round and instead convert the `encounterdate` column to a string using `DATE_FORMAT` as you do the comparison.

Documentation here:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format
- http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_format.asp

This would result in:

```
DATE_FORMAT( encounterdate, '%m-%d-%Y' ) IN ( '01-10-2012'
                                            , '01-10-2012'
                                            , '01-10-2012' )
```

However, you should bear in mind that this will have an impact on the indexing of `encounterdate`, though this might not be a problem in your use-case.

Comment: I guess you could convert encounterdate to string instead - using DATE_FORMAT, though this would limit the use of indexes on that column.  In your particular use case this might not be a problem.  See here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 0):

As it is explained in mysql manual, str_to_date function , get only to parameters. The first parameter is your date string, and the second one is the format of your date string.so you cann't use it like this:

```
STR_TO_DATE('01-10-2012','01-10-2012', '%m-%d-%Y')
```

You should use this:

```
STR_TO_DATE('01-10-2012', '%m-%d-%Y'),STR_TO_DATE('01-10-2012', '%m-%d-%Y')
```